# If $\lim_{x\to k}$ and $\lim_{xy\to k}$, under what conditions is $x = y$?

Tags: limits

Just going through some theory, and I had this thought.

If we have a limit $$\lim_{x\to k}$$ and another limit $$\lim_{y\to k}$$ will x always be equal to y, or are there specific conditions for this statement to be true?

Comment: What does it mean? You are taking the limit of what ?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ "live" only inside the limit expression, so they do not even have an opportunity to be equal

Comment: When you work with limits in multivariable calculus, such as $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$, then for the limit to exist, it has to exist without requiring any specific relationship between $x$ and $y$, such as $x=y$. Sometimes you show that such a limit does not exist by showing that the limit would have one value along a path with $x=y$, and would have a different value along some other path.

Comment: @sxnchit If I answered your question, you may want to accept it to remove it from the Unanswered tab, unless you are still finding for a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if you misunderstood the limit operator. The $x$ and the $y$ are just the variables of an expression that will approach the value $k$. Just because they will approach the same value doesn't mean that they are equal. Also, the limit operator needs an expression to be evaluated.

Take $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} (x^{2} - 1)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to 1}(y + 1)$ as an example. You can't say that $x = y$ just because both of them approaches $1$.

---

As I still know of, limits are of the form $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x).$$ You can see that we need three things:

1. An independent variable,
2. The value that the independent variable approaches,
3. The function where the limiting process applies.

In your case, you only have two things, which makes it invalid. To explain what limits are, it is as if we are asking what value does $f(x)$ approaches as $x$ approaches $a$. There are various ways to find it, and one of which is the [$\epsilon-\delta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) way.

---

By the way, the title of the question does not match with the body. I just processed what the body is.

Comment: Perfect answer (+1)